# POST json data and custom headers

Tags: ruby, curl

I have the following ruby code that I'm trying to implement in the same way that this `curl` works.

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: $APP_ID" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: $KEY" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"score": 1337, "playerName": "Sean Plott", "cheatMode": false }' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore
```

Here's the ruby code:

```
def execute_post
  puts "executing post script.."
  payload ={
    "score" => "1337",
    "playerName" => "Sean Plott", 
    "cheatMode" => "false"

  }.to_json
  headers = {
    'X-Parse-Application-Id' => $APP_ID, 
    'X-Parse-REST-API-KEY' => $KEY,
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
  }
  url = "https://" + $DOMAIN + $BASE_URL + $LIST_CLASS
  uri = URI.parse(url)
  puts uri
  puts payload

  puts "***************"
  req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.host, initheader = headers)
  req.body = payload
  response = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port).start{|http| http.request(req)}

  puts "Response #{response.code} #{response.message}: #{response.body}"

end
```

For some reason I'm getting an error. Any ideas on what's going wrong?

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:135:in `sysread': end of file reached (EOFError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:135:in `rbuf_fill'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:62:in `timeout'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:93:in `timeout'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:134:in `rbuf_fill'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:116:in `readuntil'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:126:in `readline'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:2024:in `read_status_line'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:2013:in `read_new'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:1050:in `request'
    from parse_connect.rb:33:in `execute_post'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:543:in `start'
    from parse_connect.rb:33:in `execute_post'
    from parse_connect.rb:42
```

Comment: It's hard to say because there's missing info such as all those global vars (which you shouldn't use). Anyway you're doing this the hard way, consider using mechanize or httparty

Comment: This is a just a test script (answer to global vars). The global vars don't matter as they're just used to hold variables that I don't want to reveal.

Comment: For example I can't tell from this code if you're posting to a valid url or not.

Comment: the url is valid, i've checked it using curl

Comment: I don't think you checked that you assembled it properly. Anyway, that message means network problems so either your internet is down, the host is down or your url is wrong. But like I said you should use mechanize or httparty anyway.

Comment: +1 for the day9 reference

Answer (score 1):

try it like this:

```
require 'mechanize'
Mechanize.new.post url, data.to_json, headers
```

if that doesn't work run fiddler and try it like this:

```
Mechanize.new{|a| a.set_proxy 'localhost', 8888}.post url, data.to_json, headers
```

Then inspect the request in fiddler

Comment: I get a 400 bad request for this.

Comment: ok, now proxy your curl request through fiddler so you can compare them. Where the requests are different is your problem.

Comment: up-vote +1000. 2 days and every rest client i could try and nothing worked, found this right at the end of day 2 and it just worked where everything else had failed (httpart, http-client, ect). Thank you so so much.

Answer (score 0):

In your curl example, you are using HTTPS.

You need to specifically enable HTTPS when using Net::HTTP (it's not enough to just put https:// in your URL).

```
http =  Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
response = http.start{|http| http.request(req)}
```